# How to use a string as a pointer to resources in R file

Tags: android, string, r.java-file

For example, I have a string `"R.raw.tch_swan_lake"`. I want to play one of many files in the raw folder, which match to my string:

```
melody = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tch_swan_lake);
```

How to use a string as a resource pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("tch_swan_lake", "raw", context.getPackageName()); 
    melody = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i get play able resource from 'raw;

```
 Uri uri =Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + imageName);// without extention
```